# SVG: Why <p> element is not displaying in <foreignobject>

Tags: css, html, svg

I'm attempting to put a `<p>` element inside a `<foreignobject>` inside an `<svg>` node in chrome but I am not seeing the text.  I have inspected the element and the DOM model shows the structure I expect.  I created this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujzL8yyr/) by copying from the DOM model and lo and behold it works exactly as I desire in the fiddle.

After scratching my head for a bit I started looking at the properties in the two tabs (both in Chrome) and the only 2 things at this point that jump out me are that when I hover over the `<foreignobject>` or `<p>` element in the fiddle, it shows a grey box the area where it's displayed.  When I do this in the real application, it does the same for the `<foreignobject>` but I see nothing for the `<p>` element.  The second difference is that in the fiddle, the `<p>` element shows a height and a width of 54px and 100px (respectively) but in the actual application they both are reported to be 'auto'.

As an experiment, I attempted to set the height and width explicitly in the CSS for 'p' but chrome just shows this as an 'invalid property'.

Assuming this is the problem, I'm a little lost as to how to control a property that I'm not allowed to specify.  Can someone help with some advice on how to debug this further?  There's clearly something about what I am doing that is causing this but I'm not sure where to look next.

EDIT:

I don't know why I didn't notice this before but I see a difference that may help explain this.  The fiddle shows the properties for the `<p>` element as:

- p.description
- HTMLParagraphElement
- HTMLElement
- Node
- EventTarget
- Object

The application shows these properties:

- p
- SVGElement
- Element
- Node
- EventTarget
- Object

I assume this has something to do with how d3 is adding the `<p>` element.  I will try to create a fiddle that creates the elements with d3.

Comment: What makes those objects in the page. How do you build the structure you've posted in the fiddle?

Comment: I'm using d3 (javascript)

Comment: Create a testcase and add it to the question. It's possible you're using the wrong namespace but it's hard to tell without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out.  Robert Longson's comment made some documentation from d3 finally click for me.  I was creating the `<p>` element like this (fo is the foreignobject):

```
fo.append("p").attr("xmlns", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml")
```

I changed it to this and it now displays the text:

```
fo.append("xhtml:p")
```

Thanks for the help.